# Why can't we implement a method inside the main method in Java?

Tags: java

Why doesn't this work?

```
public class AddArray
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        int[] x = {1,2,3};
        int[] y = {1,2,3};

        dd(x,y);

        public static void add(int[]a, int[]b)
        {
            int[] sum = new int[a.length];
            for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
                sum[i] = a[i] + b[i];
            for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
                System.out.println(sum[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The short of it is "it doesn't work because you are not supposed to". I'm not really sure what 'answer' you are looking for? You mean as opposed to methods in a class? or as opposed to another language? or why this would be like this?

Answer (score 8):

You can't define a method within another method in Java. In particular, you can't define a method within the `main` method.

In your case, you could write:

```
public class AddArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] x = {1,2,3};
        int[] y = {1,2,3};

        add (x,y);
    }

    private static void add (int[] a, int[] b) {
        int[] sum = new int[a.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            sum[i] = a[i] + b[i];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            System.out.println(sum[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, Java does not support nested function. But the question is why would you need that??
If you really have a situation where you want a nested method, then you can go with a `local class`.

It looks like this: -

```
public class Outer {
    public void methodA() {
         int someVar = 5;

         class LocalClass {
              public void methodB() {
                   /* This can satisfy your need of nested method */
              }
         }

         // You cannot do this instantiation before the declaration of class
         // This is due to sequential execution of your method..

         LocalClass lclassOb = new LocalClass();
         lclassOb.methodB();
    }
}
```

However, you must note that, your local class will be visible only in the scope it is defined. It cannot have modifier: `private`, `public`, or `static`.

Answer (score 2):

Methods cannot be defined inside other methods in Java. For this to compile your `add` method would have to be extracted out of the `main` method.

Comment: Why 'named methods'? AFAIK Java doesn't support unnamed ones.

Comment: Oops, typo, corrected :)

Answer (score 1):

Because the Java Language Specification does not allow it.

Methods belong directly under a class, and cannot be nested.

Answer (score 0):

In java you have to keep methods separate. :/   sorry